# Finding the horizon using ARKit?

Tags: ios, arkit

I have an app using OpenCV to produce panoramas of outdoor scenes from multiple images (gebus I wish Apple would expose their pano feature!).

I need to extract the horizon. OCV does this, but is easily fooled in the samples I tried - it thought the roof was the horizon in one case.

So maybe there is a way to do this with ARKit instead? Essentially, I want to know where the "floor" is as the user moves the camera around to take images.

Answer (score 0):

In ARKit there is the `ARHitTestResult` with various types that recognise planes (such as `estimatedHorizontalPlane`, `existingPlane` and `existingPlaneUsingExtent`. The upper edge of the plane would be your horizon.

You could try these and examine if the result is acceptable.